# What context should I refer to so I am able to BitBlt on top of any application or window? Is there a "general" context which refer to display?

Tags: winapi, bitblt

So I`m very new to win32ui, basically just starting. I was once using BitBlt wit python win32api module and as far as I remember to draw on top of display (so any application - if they are opened) I had to get specific context handle. But my memory is hazy on whether it simply was NULL or was it some specific context? Null doesn't seem to work, so I wonder how to obtain that general context? I really want to avoid to create fully transparent un blocking window.

Comment: [`GetDC(NULL)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc) is what you are asking for. The real solution is the one you are trying to avoid: Creating a transparent top-most window.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you very much :), could you put it in an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GetDC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdc) API allows you to get a device context for any given window. Alternatively,

> If [`hWnd`] is `NULL`, `GetDC` retrieves the DC for the entire screen.

You can use the device context for the entire screen to read from, reliably (with [restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowdisplayaffinity)). Rendering into a device context for a window you do not own won't be reliable, though. While it won't fail straight away, the window owner can overwrite your rendering at any point. There's no way for you to even be notified about this.

If you need to render on top of the screen you will have to create a top-most (transparent) window yourself, and use its device context. Make sure you ask the question: [What if two programs did this?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050607-00/?p=35413)